# What is an "indecomposable" matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

What is an *indecomposable* matrix? I tried to find what it is, but Wikipedia does not have an entry for it. Also, what properties does such matrix have?

Comment: You should provide some background. In what context did you find this term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this entry in Planet Math: [Fully Indecomposable Matrix](http://planetmath.org/FullyIndecomposableMatrix.html).

See also [Special matrices](http://www.psi.toronto.edu/matrix/special.html): scroll to "Decomposable". You'll find what it means to be decomposable, partly decomposable, and fully indecomposable.

---

Note: The term ***irreducible*** is usually used instead of ***indecomposable***.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducibility_%28mathematics%29): "...a matrix is *irreducible* if it is not similar via a permutation to a block upper triangular matrix (that has more than one block of positive size)." 
(Replacing non-zero entries in the matrix by one, and viewing the matrix as the adjacency matrix of a directed graph, the matrix is irreducible if and only if the digraph is irreducible.)

[PlanetMath: reducible matrix](http://planetmath.org/ReducibleMatrix.html)
 "An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is said to be a *reducible matrix* *if and only if* for some permutation matrix $P$, the matrix $P^TAP$ is block upper triangular matrix." 
*If a square matrix is not reducible, it is said to be an irreducible matrix.*

Comment: I think "irreducible" is much, much popular than "indecomposable".

Comment: I agree, @user1551 !

Answer (score 4):

An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is *reducible* if there is a permutation matrix $P$ so that

$$PAP^T=\begin{bmatrix}B&C\\0&D\end{bmatrix}$$

where $B$ and $D$ are square.
Equivalently, $A$ is reducible if it has a $k \times (n-k)$ zero submatrix with disjoint column and row indices.

If $A$ is not reducible, it is *irreducible*.

On the other hand, $A$ is *partly decomposable* if there are permutation matrices $P$ and $Q$ so that

$$PAQ=\begin{bmatrix}B&C\\0&D\end{bmatrix}$$

where $B$ and $D$ are square. Equivalently, $A$ is partly decomposable if it has a $k \times (n-k)$ zero submatrix.

If $A$ is not partly decomposable, it is *fully indecomposable* (or sometimes *totally indecomposable*).

Every fully indecomposable matrix is irreducible, but the converse is false in general.

Brualdi and Ryser's *Combinatorial Matrix Theory* provides the following comment on this terminology:

> One may wonder why the adverbs "partly" and "fully" are being used
> here. The reason is that the terminology "decomposable" and
> "indecomposable" is sometimes used in place of "reducible" and
> "irreducible." A reducible matrix of order $n$ also has a $k$ by $n-k$
> zero submatrix for some integer $k$ but the row indices and column
> indices of the zero submatrix are disjoint sets. Thus reducibility is
> a more severe restriction on a matrix than that of part
> decomposability.

*Indecomposable* almost always means *irreducible* rather than *fully indecomposable*, but most authors, as with Brualdi and Ryser above, prefer to stick to *irreducible* and *fully indecomposable*, avoiding *indecomposable*.

Answer (score 1):

We shall call two matrices $A$ and $В$ permutation equivalent, or p-equivalent, if there exist permutation matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $A=PBQ$.

An $n\times n$ nonnegative matrix is said to be partly decomposable if it contains an $s \times \left(n - s\right)$ zero submatrix. In other words, a matrix is partly decomposable if it is p-equivalent to a matrix of the form

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
X & Y\\
0 & Z
\end{matrix}\right]$$

where $X$ and $Z$ are square. If an $n\times n$ nonnegative matrix contains no 
$s \times(n - s)$ zero submatrix, it is said to be fully indecomposable.

Answer (score -1):

An irreducible matrix has a corresponding graph which is strongly connected. On the other hand, an indecomposable matrix has a corresponding graph which has a directed spanning tree. So irreducibility is a stronger condition than indecomposibility.